# Flutter Flame FlameAudio: No sound on android phone

Tags: android, flutter, dart, audio, flame

Below is a very simple piece of code. I'm using the default code provided with "new flutter project".
Sound will play under Windows, but not under Android. I don't know where to look anymore....please help

Added 2 lines to main.dart:

```
       import 'package:flame_audio/flame_audio.dart';
       FlameAudio.play('explosion.mp3');
```

### Below the full pubspec.yaml + main.dart

-------------------pubspec.yaml------------------

```
name: test_sound
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.5 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flame_audio: ^1.3.1
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/audio/
```

---

-------------------main.dart------------------

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flame_audio/flame_audio.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
      FlameAudio.play('explosion.mp3');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Apparently is with the FlameAudio version, I have the same problem

Comment: Have you tried using `audioplayers` directly?